# How to control my advanced power options on c#?

Tags: c#

I am looking for a while to control turn off hard disk after a value, turn off the display never and something like that values. My question is how can I control them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a .bat file with these codes.

cd c:\windows\system32
POWERCFG -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG -change -monitor-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG -change -disk-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG -change -disk-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG -change -standby-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG -change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG -change -hibernate-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG -change -processor-throttle-ac ADAPTIVE
POWERCFG -change -processor-throttle-dc ADAPTIVE

then

Process.Start("MyPath");

Answer (score 0):

All advanced functions that are OS-specific require using COM Interop to wrap the Windows API DLLs so they can be used in a Managed environment. I would suggest you search for the Windows SDK relevant to the version of Windows you are trying to control and then for the advanced power options there - these functions are NOT native to the .NET framework, normally.